# How to install mohatos package?

Tags: python

I tried many system to install mohatos package. Please help me out

```
$ pip install mohatos

Collecting mohatos
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mohatos (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mohatos
```

Comment: pip install mohatos worked fine for me.  What platform are you on, @RahulDev

Answer (score 0):

There are binary packages, have you tried those?

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mahotas

Comment: Also I encourage you to use miniconda instead of a vanilla python install.  I find it is WAY easier to manage packages.